# Print a boolean value with printf

Tags: java, boolean, printf

I want to print a `boolean` value with the `printf` ,but I do not know how. What I am looking for is something like this imaginary code

```
boolean car = true;
System.out.printf("%b",car);
```

The expected output should be:

```
true
```

How should I do it? Or are there any other ways to get that expected output?

Comment: Your "imaginary code" works fine for me. Please elaborate on just what your current problem is.

Answer (score 14):

I assume you are running into a buffering issue, such that your program exits before your buffer flushes. When you use `printf()` or `print()` it doesn't necessarily flush without a newline. You can use an explicit `flush()`

```
boolean car = true;
System.out.printf("%b",car);
System.out.flush();
```

or add a new-line (which will also cause a `flush()`)

```
boolean car = true;
System.out.printf("%b%n",car);
```

See also [Buffered Streams - The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html), *Flushing Buffered Streams* which says in part

> Some buffered output classes support *autoflush*, specified by an optional constructor argument. When autoflush is enabled, certain key events cause the buffer to be flushed. For example, an autoflush `PrintWriter` object flushes the buffer on every invocation of `println` or `format`.

Comment: Your ESP abilities are much better than mine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's probably all of the coffee I drink. Plus, I have run into the issue when I didn't have a `flush()` and I did have code that did an immediate exit (not with a `boolean` but with `printf()`). But also the coffee.

Answer (score 3):

The good thing is that it prints the value `true`, there is nothing wrong with your imaginary code. Alternatively you can also try

```
boolean car = true;
System.out.print(car);
System.out.printf("%b", car);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean car =true;

System.out.println(""+car);
```